# Partition a 3 * K array to K equal subarrays algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to Partition N elements array
 to K equal subarrays of 3 elements each algorithm
in order to find the max sum of the 2nd element of these triplets sorted.

```
6 <= N <= 300 

K = number of triplets

K * 3 = N
```

an example would be:

```
N = 5,8,1,5,1,2,7,2,9
```

Will create three triplets sorted: `1,5,7      1,2,5     2,8,9`

that gives us the maximum result
of all possible triplets  `( 5 + 2 + 8 ) = 15`

I know this can be solved by DP techniques but I wonder if it can be solved in other ways (more efficient)?

Comment: The example is flawed. The array has two 5s and one 8, but the sorted triplets have one 5 and two 8s.

Comment: @user3386109 - fixed the flaw. btw it doesn't change the riddle/idea

Comment: Perhaps, but getting the example right is an important part of communicating the problem to other people. Also, you can often gain valuable insight into the problem by doing examples by hand, and getting it right. The triplets now match the array, but the triplets are not optimal.

Comment: @user3386109 and that's exactly the question: how to find the optimal setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The greedy algorithm is provably optimal.

Start by sorting the array, so it's `[1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9]`. Then build triples so as to maximise the middle element in the triple. The third element must be `>=` the middle element, so we pick the largest two values along with the smallest one.

- The two largest values are 8 and 9, so the first triple is `1, 8, 9`.
- The two remaining largest values are 5 and 7, so the next triple is `1, 5, 7`.
- The two remaining largest values are 2 and 5, so the last triple is `2, 2, 5`.

This gives a total sum of 8 + 5 + 2 = 15. Note that we don't need to actually produce the partitions; after sorting the list, the K middle elements are those at indices N-2, N-4, ..., N-2K, so we can just find their sum directly:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9]
          ↑     ↑     ↑
```

---

Now let's prove you can't do better. Any partition ends up with K arrows pointing at elements of the sorted array. Each arrow must be paired with a non-arrow at a greater index, otherwise it is not the middle element from a triple, or otherwise the third element from its triple has already been used in another triple. So the density of arrows in any suffix of the array cannot exceed 1/2. Conversely, any assignment of arrows with this suffix density property is achievable as a partition, by [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Consider an assignment of arrows to array indices. If the pattern `↑ _ _` occurs, move the arrow one space to the right:

```
[..., x, y, z, ...]
 ...  ↑  _  _  SSS

becomes

[..., x, y, z, ...]
 ...  _  ↑  _  SSS
```

This does not decrease the sum of numbers-with-arrows because `x <= y`; and it leaves the density of all suffixes the same except the suffix starting at `y`. The suffix starting at `y` has A+1 arrows and U+1 non-arrows, so its density is <= 1/2 if and only if A+1 <= U+1. This holds because SSS's density is <= 1/2 implying A <= U.

It follows that the pattern `↑ _ ↑ _ ↑ _` cannot be improved on by moving some arrow to the right (since it would violate the density restriction), nor by moving some arrow to the left (since it would create a `↑ _ _`).

Comment: @PritamBanerjee - "provably optimal" is not a misspelling; it means the algorithm *is* optimal and can be proved optimal. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provably

Answer (score 2):

The first step seems to be to sort the array.

The lowest best element to take is the element at position K + 1 (index K), because you put the K lowest ones as first element in each array and then you have to put the element at position K + 1 at the 2nd position of one of the arrays.

The highest number is the element at position N - 1 (index  N - 2), this happens if you put the 2 highest elements in one array. This is also optimal, because if you spread those high numbers among more than one array, you will just lose value without any gain.

Finally for the numbers in the middle: We can get the best value again by using the next 2 highest elements (those we haven't used yet).

So the solution is to take the elements at indexes [N - 2, N - 4, N - 6, ... , K]

Or in code, time complexity O(nlogn) because of the sort, although you could theoretically get O(n) if the numbers have an upper bound (i.e. fixed number of bits) by using radix sort:

```
public int bestSum(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length / 3; i++)
        sum += arr[arr.length - 2 * i];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You can do 8 + 5 + 2 = 15 by partitioning as [1,8,9], [1,5,7] and [2,2,5].

Comment: @kaya3 No you can't. You need to put 4 numbers in each array. Hmm ok seems you are right, the question was changed, I understood it differently.

Comment: Not according to the question: *"Partition N elements array to K equal subarrays of 3 elements"*. The OP's example has subarrays of size 3, and the question title says N = 3K.

Comment: @kaya3 Corrected it, the question was changed.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it using dynamic programming solving approach.First, we will sort the array. Then we will go through the array and each time we will calculate the optimal for dp[i][j][k] where:

> (i+j+k) = m
>   m is the position of current element.
>   i is the number of element in the first set till now
>   j is the number of element in the second set till now
>   k is the number of element in third set till now

Algorithm:

```
int ar = {.....}//Given array
int dp[n/3][n/3][n/3] //For memoization,n is the number of given element

for(int i = 1;i <= n/3;i++){
   for(int j = 1;j <= n/3;j++){
      for(int k  = 1;k <= n/3;k++){
         dp[i][j][k]= max(dp[i][j][k], dp[i-1][j][k] + (i == 2)?ar[i+j+k]:0);
         dp[i][j][k]= max(dp[i][j][k], dp[i][j-1][k] + (j == 2)?ar[i+j+k]:0);
         dp[i][j][k]= max(dp[i][j][k], dp[i][j][k-1] + (k == 2)?ar[i+j+k]:0);
      }
   }
}
```

Finally ans will be stored in dp[n/3][n/3][n/3]